# ROW_NUMBER() Problems with Subqueries

Tags: sql-server

In the following example it is not possible to sort by Field_2 (Subquery)
Is there a solution?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
    Field_A,
    (SELECT Field_1 FROM Table_2) AS Field_B,
    Field_C,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Field_B ASC) AS Row_Num
    FROM Table_1
) AS Name
WHERE Row_Num BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

Comment: You can't use the alias in the same query, `Field_B` is an alias, instead you can `(ORDER BY (SELECT Field_1 FROM Table_2) ASC)`

Comment: Pretty sure `(SELECT Field_1 FROM Table_2)  AS Field_B` is going to produce an error too, along the lines of `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.` *(Unless `Table_2` only has 1 row in it, and will only ever have 1 row in it)*

Comment: Apart from sorting, this query wouldn't run at all. Would you instead give some sample data and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Larnu I think that's just for simplification's sake, but of course you are correct.

Comment: @ZoharPeled possibly, however, the error the OP is getting would be presented first, as it will be generated at the time the query is parsed. The error I've given, however, won't happen until it is run and the DBMS finds more than 1 row in the subquery. Thus it may well be the OP is unaware they're (probably) going to get another error.

Comment: @Larnu good point.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use an alias in the same select clause it was declared.
You can either repeat the subquery as demonstrated in Zaynul Abadin Tuhin's answer, or use another derived table (or a cte):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Field_B ASC) AS Row_Num
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
        Field_A,
        (SELECT Field_1 FROM Table_2) AS Field_B,
        Field_C
        FROM Table_1
    ) AS Name
) As NumberedName
WHERE Row_Num BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

Also, please note that unless Table_2 has only a single row, using `(SELECT Field_1 FROM Table_2)` as a subquery will result with an error -

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

As noted by Larnu in the comments.

Comment: Oh my another wrong answer for the 5th time :( This query would NOT run.

Comment: @CetinBasoz you might want to expand on why it won't, rather than just saying "it won't run". That isn't helpful to the OP or the person answering.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Had the OP posted sample data properly (meaning DDL+DML), I would have had a chance to check my answer before posting. I've had a comma that shouldn't have been there after `Field_C` which I've removed in my update, and of course there's the subquery issue I've already addressed. Assuming Table_2 have only one row this will run (look at the [fork from your DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1b2f11a7cd9ac94239f90678a6367a0b)) So I really don't know what is it that you think is wrong with my answer now.

Comment: @Larnu, do you think those who answer are amateurs not to know that they can't use a subquery that returns multiple rows as field selection? I actually even created and posted a link to a DBFiddle demo showing "why not" (and you already wrote the expected error itself). Unfortunately (or fortunately) post was deleted by owner and my DBFiddle demo link gone.

Comment: This SQL doesn't need a sample from OP to see the answer you wrote wouldn't work in the first place, especially if you think it was the 5th answer doing the same basic mistake and it was already noted in the comments to OP. We cannot assume, Table_2 would have one row, how many times in your life have you created a table to keep just a single row? That is nowhere realistic, so this answer wouldn't work in the first place. And if that table would have a single row then why OP would have a sorting problem?

Comment: @CetinBasoz then you statement isn't completely correct. For all we know `Table_2` might only ever contain 1 row, and thus the query will run. Still, just saying "this won't run" without explanation format help anyone.

Comment: @Larnu, no OP implicitly states that table_2 have more than one rows by asking about sorting on it. With one row he wouldn't have a sorting problem, would he?

Comment: The answer here actually acknowledges the problem, which is the most we can do. The OP is then aware and can eloborate if they encounter the error.

Comment: @Larnu, Which answer?

Comment: This answer that we are commenting on.

Comment: (Part 1/2) @CetinBasoz Well, I have multiple databases with a configuration table that only has one row in it, that might very well be the case here. Further more, the subquery error we are talking about was acknowledged by Larnu in the comments and also by me starting with the first version of this answer - and in any case, this is not what the OP is asking about. Clearly the answer to the question asked (not the problems the sample code has to bring with it) is that you can't reference the alias in the same select clause it was declared.

Comment: (Part 2/2) @CetinBasoz I agree that answers that ignores the subquery error are wrong, however my answer never ignored it - on the contrary - I've quoted Larnu's comment and added the part (since then being added into the comment as well) about the exception to the rule if the table only contains one row.  So IMHO, downvoting this answer because "It won't run" is wrong. It's not supposed to run, it's supposed to show the OP how to handle what they asked about. Also, please note that it's possible that the subquery issue does not exists in the OP's actual code - see my comment on the question.

Comment: Once again, OP's question implicitly tells that subquery is returning multiple rows. I don't understand what made you think it was returning only one row. Down voting was just right because despite you know it returns more than one rows you had it there as if it would work but I will revoke it just to make you happy.

Comment: If you think the downvote is correct, go ahead and keep it, It wouldn't make me sad or happy. I can live my life quite fine without those two reputation points. If you still think I'm wrong - by all means - downvote all you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use alias you have to use that sub-query on order by

```
   with cte as (
        SELECT
        Field_A,
        (SELECT Field_1 FROM Table_2
        ) AS Field_B, --- it should have to rerun 1 value otherwise it will thrown error , so i think here need where condition
        Field_C       
        FROM Table_1
         ) , cte2 as    
         ( select *, row_number() over(order by Field_B asc) rn
           from cte
          ) select * from cte where rn>=1 and rn<=100
```

Comment: Would this really run?